# ORA-00911: invalid character in sqlfiddle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to build an SQL Schema as shown

```
CREATE TABLE Persons3
(
City varchar2(255)
);


CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
BEGIN
Select 2 from dual ;
END//
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4

I am getting Schema Creation Failed: ORA-00911: invalid character

Could any body please explain whats invalid in that sql fiddle ??

Comment: Did you select an alternate delimiter in the dropdown below the left hand textbox? If so you need to use that delimiter for **all** statements (and I think it needs to be on a line of its own as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different terminators. If you've set the terminator as `//` thenyou have to use that for all statements. Your first statement, `CREATE TABLE`, is currently terminated by `;` and it is that character which invalid, because of the statement terminator setting.

Your procedure is invalid anyway - it's missing an `into` as others have said, and is also missing a semicolon after the `END`. Which might sound confusing, but the semicolon in the PL/SQL context (within that single statement) stays even if the *statement* separator is something else.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons3
(
City varchar2(255)
)
//


CREATE PROCEDURE myProc AS
  x number;
BEGIN
  select 2 into x from dual;
END;
//
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5a1c/1).

Using a single `/` would be more usual for Oracle, but the same applies - whatever separator you choose, it has to be applied consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure call is wrong. You always have to select `into` something in PL/SQL. Also your procedure end is a little odd:

```
create procedure myProc
as
  v pls_integer;
begin
  select 2
  into   v
  from   dual
  ;
end;
```